# How to fill models attributes with data from internet

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

First of all let me say that I'm new to Django.

I've created a small application that gathers information from trasnfermrkt to create football players.

In my Models I've defined Player with some attributes: name, age, position... One of the attribute is the trasnfermrkt URL link. I'd like to add the URL and the application to auto-filled all the attributes using info from that URL.

The function that collects info from transfermrkt is not part of the Model (I'm trying to follow the services module approach) so, from Models, I'm modifying the save method to call the external function.

So far this appraoch is working, but I'd like to know if there's a better approach for what I want to achieve (maybe using signals?).

scrapping.py

```py
class PlayerData():
  """Class that gathers data from transfermrkt. It needs a URL"""
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

  def get_transfrmrkt(self):
    page = self
    pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=PlayerData.headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
    player_name = soup.find("div", class_="dataMain").find("h1").text
[...]
```

models.py

```py
from library.scrapping import PlayerData 
[...]
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name=PlayerData.get_transfrmrkt(self.transfermarkt_link)
    # Call the "real" save()
    super(Player, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Making your model's `save()` method depending on the result of a HTTP request is  possibly one of the worst possible ideas indeed (if you don't see why, ask yourself in how many different ways this can fail).

As far as I understand your question, there are two aspects to it: 1/ populating the database and 2/ keeping it up to date wrt/ the "trasnfermrkt" site.

For the first part (and assuming you can get all required fields from the trasnfermrkt link) the solution would be to write a custom management command that takes a list of trasnfermrkt urls (or a text file containing such a list, one per line), query those urls and create the playerdata records from those urls (first filtering out existing records of course).

Eventually, depending on what you can get from the trasnfermrkt site, you may even change the command to **scrape** the urls directly from the site.

*A note of caution though: be polite and leave a decent wait time between each request so you don't overload the site... Oh and yes - make sure this is ok from the website's terms of use, and if it isn't contact them to try and find a legal agreement.*

For the second part, a similar custom management command would iterate over the existing records, query the url and update the records from the response. This command is then supposed to be executed by some scheduler (`cron` or whatever) like once a day or so depending on how often those data change - and on what the site allows of course.

Since most of those commands code will be the same, you can extract it into distinct functions that are called by both commands - and can also be used in a custom ModelAdmin to create new players from the url itself in the admin.